# How to solve this issue in a URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

How to encrypt and decrypt the Query string and sent,receive to another page?

#### Page 1

```
LinkButton InvoiceEdit = sender as LinkButton;
string EditId = InvoiceEdit.CommandArgument.ToString();
Response.Redirect("edit invoice.aspx?EditId=" + EditId);
```

#### Page 2

```
String invoiceId = Request.QueryString["InvoiceId"].ToString();
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sounds like the other .aspx page is doing what it should.

Comment: @Ayyappan: your question is being downvoted because it frankly makes no sense.  Please try to explain the problem you're seeing more clearly.

Comment: I encrypt my value and send to page 2.again i decrypt the it here and using.

Ya i find the solution guys..Thanks to all down voters.

Comment: I'm still hella confused. The source code isn't helping any if we don't even understand the problem, mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. what i understand that seems u want to restrict user to modified url. you can user URL Referrer check on page load
if Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri == null
 {
    Response.redirect("home page")
 }

If someone tried to modify url it will alway return null and you can redirect to home page or some other page to restrict the user.

Comment: thanks man this is wt i expect

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't know what's your exact issue. But here I should say:

1. Do not put those financial related parameters in the query string.
2. Do you mean that when you change the URL in the browser from `xx.aspx?editid=5` to `xx.aspx?editid=4`, the invoice in your page also changes? The reason is, `editid=4` means the invoice you loaded is the one whose id is 4 while `editid=5` will display the invoice whose id is 5. If you want to get the same result when browsing `editid=4` and `editid=5`, just make the two invoices same. haha

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanna change editid but some value NOT-Changed after editid changed. I think you can use viewstate to help.